# Using counter in condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Imagine I have the following code:

```
i=0
while True:
    if flag==True and i=i+5:
        func()
    .
    .
    .
    i+=1
    break
```

shouldn't be `i==i+5`?

I want to run `func()` each 5 times.

Comment: `i == i +5` will never be true by definition. You need to have separate variables for counter and current step.

Comment: Is `flag` True during a 5 iteration period of the loop (you said it must be run 5 times) or it may change during that loop?

Comment: Btw: i=i+5 is illegal in a condition (in Python. In C, it is legal, and a source of very nasty bugs). And don't write `if (flag == True):`, simply write `if flag:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i = i + 5` is always true unless previous value of `i` is `-5`. However, `if i = i + 5` is invalid syntax. `i == i + 5` is always false. In `if flag == True` portion explicit comparing with True is redundant. `if flag` is sufficient.

Now come to the main question. If you want to call `func` in every five iteration of the loop then you have to use modules operator.

```
while True:
    if flag and i % 5 == 0:
        func()
    # Other stuffs that you want to run at each iteration
```

And if you have a break at end of while loop then it will immediately break after first iteration. Ideally, a `break/continue` statements should be inside an `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` is divisible by 5:

```
i % 5 == 0
```